# Understanding the size of an array of char pointers

Tags: c++, c

```
char * names[] = {
              "Sleepy",
              "Dopey" "Doc",
              "Happy",
              "Grumpy" "Sneezy",
              "Bashful",
};
```

`sizeof(names)` results in 40.

But logically speaking sizeof counts string length plus null character. Why is the size 40?

Comment: 5 elements that are 64 bit (8 bytes) pointers. 40 bytes.

Comment: FYI, `"Grumpy" "Sneezy"` is the same as `"GrumpySneezy"`. It doesn't seem like this was intended.

Comment: ... same for `"Dopey" "Doc"`!

Answer (score 10):

Your array contains five pointers, and on your platform `sizeof(char*)` is `8` - so 5*8 = 40.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of sizes here: size of each char array (what you describe in your question) and size of `names`, which is an array of pointers.

For example:

```
auto size_array = sizeof(names) / sizeof(char*); // (should yield 5)
```

String length:

```
auth e0_length = std::strlen(names[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use std::array or a vector?  These have length methods that will keep track of the number of elements for you.
Alternatively, you could use:

```
 sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0])
```

to help with system independence.